# Python - Find the number of duplicates in a string text

Tags: python, string, text, count, duplicates

I want to write a function that returns the number of alphabetic characters and numeric digits that occur more than once in an input string.

Sample example: "aabbccd" should return 3 since "a","b" and "c" all have duplicates. Same for "aaabbccd", that would return 3 as well.

Here is what I did, but it seems that there's something wrong with my code. It worked on some cases but apparently it does not on others.

```
def duplicate_count(text):
  count=0
  for i in range(len(text)-1):
      for j in range(i+1,len(text)):
          if text[i]==text[j]:
              count+=1
              break
      break
  return count
```

Comment: I don't think that 2nd `break` should be there?

Answer (score 7):

One simple way of doing it is :

```
def duplicate_count(s):
    return len([x for x in set(s) if s.count(x) > 1])
```

Answer (score 2):

This one would be more concise:

```
import numpy as np

def duplicate_count(text):

    #elem is an array of the unique elements in a string
    #and count is its corresponding frequency
    elem, count = np.unique(tuple(text), return_counts=True)

    return np.sum(count>1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a native approach without resorting to expensive `str.count()` (although performance depends on the length of the string and the duplicate characters) in pure O(N) time:

```
def duplicate_count(text):
    seen = set()
    return len({char for char in text if char in seen or seen.add(char) is not None})

print(duplicate_count("aabbccd"))
# 3
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not keeping track of letters you've already counted.

Consider the input `aaa`. The code takes the first `a` and searches for another `a`. It finds one, so it increments `count`. Then the code moves on to the 2nd `a`. It searches for another `a` (again), finds one, and increments `count` (again).

Use a set to keep track of which letters you've already counted.

Answer (score 1):

Another one line solution:

```
import collections
def duplicate_count(text):
    return len(list(filter(lambda x:x[1]>1,collections.Counter(text).items())))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a approach using dict.

```
import collections
your_string='aabbssesd'
d = collections.defaultdict(int)
for c in your_string:
    d[c] += 1
d = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if v>1}
print(len(d))
```

The defaultdict will simply create any items that you try to access (provided they don't exist yet).

`d = collections.defaultdict(int)`

This will output a key value pair for number of occurences of characters in the string like.

```
{'e': 1, 'a': 2, 'r': 1, 's': 2}
```

Use dict comprehension to store only key k,value v pair from dict and if value v is greater than 1. (more than one occurence)

```
d = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if v>1}
```

It's output

```
{'a': 2, 's': 2}
```

Then `print(len(d))` to get number of duplicates

Comment: It isn't particularly faster than any of the other approaches though.

Comment: That's actually the slowest approach of all presented.